# Do all finite $W$-superalgebras have 1-dimensional representations?

Tags: modular-representation-theory, lie-superalgebras, lie-algebras, rt.representation-theory

Premet proved the famous KW-conjecture in modular Lie algebra.
After, Premet introduced the finite $W$-algebra $U(g, e)$.
Also,  Premet proposed the conjecture every algebra $U(g, e)$ admits a $1$-dimensional
representation
then, Losev proved this conjecture for g classical.

so, a natural question,
for the super version, what about these results when we consider the basis classical Lie superalgebra,i.e, whether every super W-algebra admits a $1$-dim rep??

**EDIT**: Thanks for  Professor José Figueroa-O'Farrill pointing out that 
in the literature of mathematical physics, the finite
W-algebras appeared in the work of de Boer and Tjin from the viewpoint
of BRST quantum hamiltonian reduction.

Comment: Not to take any credit away from Premet, but finite W-algebras were introduced by Tjark Tjin in a 1992 paper of that name, published in  Phys. Lett. B292, 60 (1992).  (http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1184379)


Comment: @José Figueroa-O'Farrill , thank you very much. I apologize for inadequate references in this regard.
I just want to say the finite $W$-algebras 
were introduced by Premet  into mathematics in a different terminology.

Comment: @wison: no problem and thanks for the edit.  Let me just emphasise that Tjark's paper, despite being published in a Physics journal, is actually reasonably mathematical.  He considers an important special case of what are now known as finite W-algebras.
 